# Celeryd not running properly in django

Tags: python, linux, celery, daemon

For about 1 month `celeryd` was working fine but now i noticed that celeryd have stopped working .
I tried to restart celery but it gives error .

Below are the commands that i tried to start celery ...

```
Command1 : service celeryd status
Response1 : celeryd (node worker1) (pid 4806) is stopped, but pid file exists!

Command2 : service celeryd start
Response : Stale pidfile exists. Removing it

Command3 : service celeryd stop
Response : celery multi v3.1.25 (Cipater) 
           worker1: DOWN
```

Can anyone tell what is the problem behind that ? 
how to restart celeryd ?

**Note: celery is running as daemon**

Comment: Check logs first. What distribution of Linux is this?

Comment: there is no error in log and system is running on ubuntu @Selcuk

Answer (score 1):

As you stated, celeryd is working in background, you have to stop or kill that process first.

`ps aux|grep celeryd`

this command will return:

`root  **12717**  0.0  0.0  21536  1076 pts/3    S+   12:24   0:00 grep --color=auto celeryd`

Here 12717 is process ID for celeryd. You can kill the process by using:

`sudo kill -9 PROCESS-ID`

Run `ps aux|grep celeryd` to ensure process is killed and no other process is started with the same.

Now run `sudo service celeryd start`

Answer (score 0):

you have a typical error the process is running in secondary part and this is normal where bad turn off you shouldn't to kill the process manually

```
kill -9 4806
```

try it and restart the centry daemon

```
sudo systemctl reload celeryd
```

I hope I can help you